# ValueError in kNN metrics

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, knn, valueerror

I have a project that consists of utilizing the kNN algorithm in a csv file and show selected metrics. But when I try to present some metrics it throws a few errors.

When trying to use: **sensitivity**, **f1_Score** and **Precision**:

1. sensitivity - print(metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred_class))
2. F1_score - print(metrics.f1_score(y_test, y_pred_class))
3. Presicion - print(metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred_class))

Pycharm throws the following error:

> **ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting**

The error when trying to print the ROC curve's a little different:

> **ValueError: multiclass format is not supported**

---

## DATASET

[image: DATASET:]

LINK TO DATASET: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yt3n1eqxlsb816n/Testfile%20-%20kNN.csv?dl=0

## Program

```
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dviread import Text

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

#Tools para teste
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def main():
    dataset = pd.read_csv('filetestKNN.csv')

    X = dataset.drop(columns=['Label'])
    y = dataset['Label'].values

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,     random_state=0, test_size=0.34)

    Classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, p=2, metric='euclidean')
    Classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_pred_class = Classifier.predict(X_test)
    y_pred_prob = Classifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

    accuracy = Classifier.score(X_test, y_test)

    confusion = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_class)

    print()
    print("Accuracy")
    print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_class))
    print()
    print("Classification Error")
    print(1 - metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_class))
    print()
    print("Confusion matrix")
    print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_class))
    #error
    print(metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred_class))
    #error
    print(metrics.roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_class))
    #error
    print(metrics.f1_score(y_test, y_pred_class))
    #error
    print(metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred_class))
```

I just wanted to show the algorithm metrics on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `average` keyword argument to these `sklearn.metrics` functions. For an example, look at the [documentation of `f1_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html). Here is the part corresponding to the `average` keyword arg:

> average : string, [None, ‘binary’ (default), ‘micro’, ‘macro’,
>   ‘samples’, ‘weighted’]
>
> This parameter is required for multiclass/multilabel targets. If None, the scores for each class are returned. Otherwise, this
>   determines the type of averaging performed on the data:
>
> ```
> 'binary':
>   Only report results for the class specified by pos_label. This is applicable only if targets (y_{true,pred}) are binary.
> 'micro':
>   Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, false negatives and false positives.
> 'macro':
>   Calculate metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean. This does not take label imbalance into account.
> 'weighted':
>   Calculate metrics for each label, and find their average weighted by support (the number of true instances for each label).
> ```
>
> This alters ‘macro’ to account for label imbalance; it can result in
>   an F-score that is not between precision and recall.
>       'samples':
>         Calculate metrics for each instance, and find their average (only meaningful for multilabel classification where this differs from
>   accuracy_score).

Here we can see that this describes how results are aggregated over the different labels on your multiclass task. I'm not sure which one you'd like to use, but `micro` seems nice. Here's how your call to `f1_score` would look with this choice:

```py
print(metrics.f1_score(y_test, y_pred_class, average='micro'))
```

You can adjust the other metrics similarly. Hope this helps.